# Version conflict: pygsl and gsl

Tags: python, gsl, pygsl

Trying to use `pygsl` library I have got this error:

```
Warning: This pygsl module was compiled for GSL version 1.16 but it
is used with version 1.15!
```

`gsl` is installed in version 1.16. The version of `pygsl` is 0.9.5 Compiling from scratch, I have first installed  `gsl` and than `pygsl` connected to the latest version of `gsl`. In `env` there is no information regarding to `gsl` or `pygsl`. This error arises because the compiled gsl version is not coincided with running gsl version. How can I tell to python which version of gsl I want to run? In any case, what else may cause this error and how could I fix it?

Comment: How did you install pygsql? What does your env look like? Please share more details (versions of pygsl/gsl, virtualenv/buildout/..).

Comment: I have added some info